# Cursor on android is not returning any rows.

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, rows

Im making an app on android and Im using an Sqlite database.
Basically, the app just inserts some numbers and then it navigates through all the rows to get the total sum of these numbers. It does that everytime the button is clicked.

But the problem is that, actually the app was working well. I just changed a little picture and then run the app again on my cell phone, but then it stop making the sum of these numbers. I used the debug option to see if the numbers were being inserted properly and the actually are. But I found out that the cursor is not getting any rows from the query. I dont know what the problem is. I really dont remmember altering the code, just changing the picture with paint. I checked the rows names, the tables names and everything is alright. I even did ctrl+z in a great desperation burst but nothing changed. I unistalled the app from my phone, clean, build and then run it again and same results.

here is the code that is involved in this operations.

```
public void crearTablas (SQLiteDatabase bd){
    bd.execSQL("Create Table If Not Exists Gasto (ID Integer Primary Key, Descripcion Text Not Null, Costo Real Not Null, Fecha_Creado Datetime not null);");
}


public void insertarGasto(String descripcion, double costo, String fechaCreado{
    ContentValues valores=new ContentValues();
    valores.putNull("ID");
    valores.put("Descripcion", descripcion);
    valores.put("Costo", costo);
    valores.put("Fecha_Creado", fechaCreado);
    bd.insert("Gasto", null, valores);
}


public void crearGastoVar(String descripcion, double costo){
    //redondear(double) is working well, i verified it!
    bd.insertarGasto(descripcion, this.redondear(costo), fecha.get(Calendar.DATE)+"-"+(fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}

public Cursor obtenerGastosVar(String fecha1, String fecha2){
    return bd.query("Gasto", null, "Fecha_Creado between '"+fecha1+ "' and '"+fecha2+"'", null, null, null, null, null);
}


public double caluclarCostoGstsVar(){
    Cursor c = bd.obtenerGastosVar("1-"+(fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
            fecha.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"-"+(fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    double costo=0;
    if(c.moveToFirst()){ //This is returning false!!
        do{
            try{
                Log.i("Look", "Sum is:"+costo);
                costo+=Double.parseDouble(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Costo")));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                Log.i("Look", "Types are wrong");
                return -2;
            }

        }while(c.moveToNext());

    }


    return redondear(costo);
}


String descrip_ = "number1";
double costo_ = 1000;

//I called before, crearTablas() so the tables are created before start inserting and reading

admin.crearGastoVar(descrip_, costo_);

admin.caluclarCostoGstsVar();
```

Comment: You may check in DDMS if your database is created indeed, first of all in /data/<your_app_package_name>/databases

Comment: i think its been created well, becuase i had some other values stored in another table that are getting inserted and queried all right. I think im gonna try makig a query with a select * in that problematic table to see if there are still empty rows. Thats a very good idea you gave me! Thanks!! :)

Comment: What are the date values in the query? What are the values in a record that you think should match?

Comment: Hi!  The value that im using to compare in the where clause is fecha_creado which is a date time value in the row. But here is the thing. Luckily i did a backup of my project before i screwed it up. and did some modifications in the dates strings. What i dont get is why inserting the rows with a date format yyyy-mm-dd and using the format dd-mm-yyyy in the queries is working very well. I tried setting the same formats in both inserting and queries commands, but if the have the same format either de-mm-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd they dont work well.

Comment: The project is working fine now. I still have this question about the dates, it had never happened to me before hehe. But everything is going well so far. Thanks to all you guys that tried to help me, you gave me good advices that im going to follow in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format provided database is created properly

```
if (cursor != null) {

      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

          do {
                       //your code

              }

           while (cursor.moveToNext());

         }

  cursor.close();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. I did what you say, but still movetofirst() returns false. It seems that the query is not done well, but i dont know why. I try using date format as yyyy-mm-dd but still not working. Anyway, thanks for your help  :)
At least i know that the cursor is not null :)

Answer (score 0):

Dates/times can be stored in [several formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but if you use strings and want to compare them, you *must* use a format like `yyyy-mm-dd` (with padded fields and the most significant field first) because otherwise, string comparisons would not give correct results.

Cursors can be read with a simple `while` loop:

```
Cursor c = ...;
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
c.close();
```

(Functions like `query` never return a `null` cursor, and `moveToNext` does the right thing for a cursor that is positioned before the first entry.)

Comment: Hi! i changed the format of the date in the query and on the insert function, to yyyy-mm-dd and is still not returning any rows at all. movtonextfirst() is still returning false so it doesnt even get into the loop :(. Anyway thank you very much for your help  :)